# How to copy collection from localhost to remote mongo instance

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

```
db.runCommand({cloneCollection : "newdb.rep", from:"localhost:27017"})
```

I am connected to the remote Mongo instance now.
However I understand this is majorly used to copy a collection from remote to local and not the other way round

Answer (score 1):

you could use this script, which will connect to local and remote database.

Some info [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/)

Then iterate via collection and insert in bulks of 1000 documents.

```
var localConnection = connect("localhost:27017/myDatabase");
var destinationConnection = connect("localhost:27020/myDatabase");

var documentLimit = 1000;
var docCount = localConnection.find({}).count();

var chunks = docCount / documentLimit;

for (var i = 0; i <= chunks; i++) {

    var bulk = destinationConnection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

    localConnection .find({}).snapshot()
    .limit(documentLimit).forEach(function (doc) {
        bulk.insert(doc);
    });

    bulk.execute()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@profesor79's script doesn't work with the newer version of MongoDB and for collections containing more than 1000 documents without some changes. It doesn't use skip() so MongoDB throws error when it tries to override the first 1000 docs again.

I have used the following script successfully on a collection containing around 20000 documents.

```
var localConnection = connect(
  "<db_user>:<db_password>@localhost:27017/<db_name>"
);
var destinationConnection = connect(
  "<db_user>:<db_password>@<remote_host>:<remote_port>/<remote_db>"
);

var documentLimit = 1000;
var docCount = localConnection.collection_name.count();

var chunks = docCount / documentLimit;

for (var i = 0; i <= chunks; i++) {
  var bulk = destinationConnection.collection_name.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

  localConnection.collection_name
    .find({})
    // after each iteration skip 1000, 2000 and so on...
    .skip(i*documentLimit)
    .limit(documentLimit)
    .forEach(function(doc) {
      bulk.insert(doc);
    });

  bulk.execute();
}
```

Provide your own local and destination connection strings and documentLimit (i.e. number of documents to be processed as a chunk) and it should work.